# no IBOutlets in Interface Builder in iOS

Tags: ios, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have declared IBOutlets in the header file but when I open the XIB file and click on the View(my class is a UIViewController sublass adopting TableViewDelegate), I see only the referencing outlets and no IBOutlet. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NamRatha, go to File's Owner file in your Nib file, now go to the last tab in the inspector. In the class Identity choose from the list your class. You should be able to see now your IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your class on the controller reference, not the view.

Comment: I did not understand. Could you please explain?